# Jupyter-like setup with org-babel in spacemacs

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-babel, jupyter

I've been trying to switch my data-analysis workflow from `Jupyter lab/notebook` to `org-mode` + `org-babel` for quite a while.

- I'm looking for an emacs setup that will provide all the functionalities of jupyter (code completion, inline docs, easy code block navigation and editing, etc.) while still working in org-mode.
- I tried to get this going in the basic emacs, in scimax and in spacemacs but none of them really did the trick. Scimax seemed to do a very good job emulating a jupyter notebook but I really missed all the out-of-the-box features from spacemacs.
- I use *spacemacs* as my day-to-day *emcas* and would really love to incorporate this kind of setup into my spacemacs configuration.
- Ideally, this setup would be a complete configuration that will work out of the box (I'm not very strong on emacs-lisp), but a (very) detailed guide for how to set this up on my own inside spacemacs would also be nice.

Comment: Did you check the scimax layer for spacemacs? You can check it here: https://github.com/dangom/scimax-layer

Comment: Yes I did try Scimax ( see 2nd bullet). It's a good option but as I said, I was really hoping to get this running on spacemacs. Maybe I'll give scimax another go.

Comment: I'm afraid the main point was missed. This link (https://github.com/dangom/scimax-layer) is a layer *for spacemac*, so with that you can try scimax with spacemac (that I understood you had issue - but you didn't use this additional layer)

Comment: @neuroprinciplist I tried the scimax layer sometime in the past, but somehow could not configure that to work. I'll that again too.

Comment: @neuroprinciplist I was now able to load the scimax-layer but this doesn't seem to provide too many features (or possibly I dont know how to use it since documentation is very sparse).